# .ajax() wont work in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new to jquery. I am trying to send an email to my php using ajax() from jquery, and then get it back to my jquery. But the program wont work.

I would like to relay the email as it is being typed. $.post(..) is working fine in valid() function in jquerying.js file, but $.ajax(...) is not. I would like to make $.ajax(...) in valid() function in jquerying.js work

**There is a problem in the $.ajax(... ) in the valid() function in jquerying.js file**

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charse="utf-8">
<title> jquerying </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquerying.css"/>   

</head>

<body>

<br/>   
<form>
Email: <input id="em" type="email"/> </input>
<input id="sub" type="submit"> </input>
<div id="emailf"> </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerying.js"> </script>

</body>

</html>
```

My jquerying.js file is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#em').focusin(function()
{
    if($(this).val()=='')
    {
        $('#emailf').html('Enter your email');
    }
    else
    {
        valid($(this).val());
    }
}).blur(function()
{
    $('#emailf').html('');
}).keyup(function()
{
    if($(this).val()!='')
    {
        $('#emailf').html('');
        valid($(this).val());
    }
    else
    {
        $('#emailf').html('Enter your email');
    }
});
});

function valid(emailer)
{
$.ajax({url: 'email.php', type: 'POST', data: {emailer: emailer},
       function(info)
       {
            $('#emailf').html(info);
       }
       });
/*  $.post('email.php', {data: emailer}, function(info)
{
    $('#emailf').html(info);
}); */
}
```

**In the valid() function in jquerying.js file, $.post( ...) is working fine btw!**

My email.php is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['emailer']))
{
    $email= $_POST['emailer'];
    echo $email;
}       
?>
```

Comment: `But the program wont work.` What seems to go wrong? What do you want it to do and what does it do instead? Does your browser console display any errors?

Comment: So I would like to relay the email as it is being typed. $.post(..) is working fine in valid() function in jquerying.js file, but $.ajax(...) is not. I would like to make $.ajax(...) in valid() function in jquerying.js work

Comment: @Viren the usage of your `$.ajax` is wrong. You're missing a response handler e.g. `.done(function(info) { /*response handler*/ });`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for the AJAX call looks incorrect. [Here is the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

And here's what your call should look like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'email.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : { emailer : emailer }
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log("success", data);
    $('#emailf').html(data);
})
.fail(function (data) {
    console.log("error", data);
})
```

Comment: @Viren No problem. By the way, Developer Tools would have told you this. In Chrome: `CMD+OPT+J` or Menu->more tools->Javascript Console. Other browsers' consoles are accessed similarly.